# Adding annotations on an image that can move in a canvas style tag

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to do something that seems simple, but I just can't do it.

I want to have an image that can be zoomed in and out, probably in a canvas (this I can do it).

But, I want to be able to put annotations on this image, like annotations on a map. I could also do this, with an html list positioned on the image.

Problem is, I have no idea how to merge these two concept into one, I know I can't really put html in the canvas, so forget about the li there.

Example of what I would like to be able to do (this is done in flash): http://www.digitalwanderer.net/darksun/

Any one has any ideas of the way to go to reproduce something like that in html?

Comment: You can create circles and squares on the canvas and let the position scale with the zoom, then you can check whether if your mouse cursor intersect with one of the squares/circles

Comment: And about the annotations?

Comment: if you intersect with the object you can trigger an alert or draw text